# Python property on a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I just discovered the properties. It works just fine when I try it on a simple variable but I cannot make it work on a list. When executing the code below it will call two times the getter and not the setter. I know that in my example the property has no added value but it is to simplify.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = [1, 2, 3]

    @property
    def x(self):
        print("getter")
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print("setter")
        self._x = value

c = C()
c.x[1] = 4
print(c.x[1])
```

Does anybody have an idea about what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The setter/getter are only used if you directly get or set the property:

```
c.x           # getter
c.x = [1,2,3] # setter
```

If you modify an element in the property you get the property and then set the corresponding element. Your example is equivalent to

```
d = c.x       # getter again
d[1] = 4
```

You could also use `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to directly allow setting and getting specific items.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = [1, 2, 3]

    @property
    def x(self):
        print("getter")
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print("setter")
        self._x = value

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print("getitem")
        return self._x[idx]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        print("setitem")
        self._x[idx] = value

>>> c = C()
>>> c[1] = 3
setitem
>>> c.x
getter
[1, 3, 3]
>>> c[2]
getitem
3
```

Comment: Do you really want to call c[1] = 3 ?! What if the class had two lists?!

Comment: @MahshidZeinaly If the class has two lists then you probably shouldn't use the `__getitem__` or `__setitem__` approach or you need to heavily modify it. I only thought about one list when I wrote the code but without further information it's a bit ambiguous. Which one should change when? Or both?

Comment: Could you explain a bit about why we shouldn't decorate __getitem__ and __setitem__ when the class has two lists?

Comment: @Frank Because it becomes ambiguous. Which of your two lists do you want to index with `__getitem__`? If it's not ambiguous then go for it - it just requires that you need to think about it in advance.

Comment: I see. I thought there were all decorated by @x.setter. Thank you!

Comment: If you have 2 lists, your best bet is probably to subclass list and put your custom `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` on that. Then use your custom list in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `c.x[1] = 4` is in fact split into two operations:

1. get the "x" property of c (=> getter)
2. set item on the resulting object.

There is no easy way how to get out of this. But anyway, in the end it does what you wanted, no?

The setter would be called, if you wrote something like:

```
c.x = another_list
```

Comment: Ok so there is no way to use a setter property with the syntax c.x[1]=4 ?

Comment: No. MSeifert's answer shows the possible alternative.